# Mailer Error: The following From address failed: Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, email

I am using `PHPMailer` using `SMTP` to send Email. I have set everything.
But in the last I am getting error :
 `Mailer Error: The following From address failed: Email Address : Called Mail() without being connected`

I came to know to set Order of coding, I also did it but still same error. Please help me to solve this issue.

**My Code :**

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "example@outlook.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->From = "info@neelcomputech.com";
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress("info@neelcomputech.com");

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;

$mail->Body = $mail_body = "<html> <body>";
$mail_body = "<b>Hello Admin,</b><br><br>You have got email from your website.<br><br>";
$mail_body .= '<table style="" cellpadding="3">';
$mail_body .= "
                <tr>
                <td width='50'> <strong> Name </strong> </td>
                <td width='5'> : </td>
                <td> $name </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Email </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $email </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <strong> Message </strong> </td>
                <td> : </td>
                <td> $message </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </body> </html>"; 

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo 'success';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    require 'PHPMailer.php';

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Host = "smtp.neelcomputech.com"; // Your SMTP PArameter
    $mail->Port = 587; // Your Outgoing Port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // This Must Be True
    $mail->Username = "info@neelcomputech.com"; // Your Email Address
    $mail->Password = "YOUR PASSWORD"; // Your Password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Check Your Server's Connections for TLS or SSL

    $mail->From = "info@neelcomputech.com";
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->AddAddress("info@neelcomputech.com");

    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;

    $mail->Body = $mail_body = "<html> <body>";
    $mail_body = "<b>Hello Admin,</b><br><br>You have got email from your website.<br><br>";
    $mail_body .= '<table style="" cellpadding="3">';
    $mail_body .= "
                    <tr>
                    <td width='50'> <strong> Name </strong> </td>
                    <td width='5'> : </td>
                    <td> $name </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td> <strong> Email </strong> </td>
                    <td> : </td>
                    <td> $email </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td> <strong> Message </strong> </td>
                    <td> : </td>
                    <td> $message </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </body> </html>"; 

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'success';
    }

    ?>
```

You have to use your own parameters, in your smtp authentication.
Also you can check other mail server's smtp parameters on PHPMailer's Website:
[phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tip_srvrs](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tip_srvrs)

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve this by using the following code:

`$mail->Host = 'relay-hosting.secureserver.net';`

Answer (score 0):

It took me a lot of digging to figure out the CentOS 7 disables SMTP connections by default, and its not through Firewalld.

Try running these lines if you run into this " Mailer Error: The following From address failed: " and "Called Mail() without being connected."

sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1

sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Thanks to the following web article:
https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix